# Using a .pfx file for Solr HTTPS

Tags: solr

**EDIT: SOLUTION: NEVER USE SPECIAL CHARACTERS IN YOUR SOLR.IN.CMD. IT WILL NOT WORK!**

I have a certificate named "cert.pfx" from  our organisation with the passwort "123456".

I want to use this file to enable https in Solr. I converted the pfx file to the desired .jks file:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12

D:\openssl\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in solr-ssl.keystore.jks.p12 -out solr-ssl.pem
```

**Output:**

- solr-ssl.keystore.jks
- solr-ssl.keystore.jks.p12
- solr-ssl.pem

**Solr.in.cmd file:**

```
REM Enables HTTPS. It is implictly true if you set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE. Use this config
REM to enable https module with custom jetty configuration.
set SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true
REM Uncomment to set SSL-related system properties
REM Be sure to update the paths to the correct keystore for your environment
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=D:\openssl\solr-ssl.keystore.jks
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=123456
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=D:\openssl\solr-ssl.keystore.jks
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=123456
REM Require clients to authenticate
set SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
REM Enable clients to authenticate (but not require)
set SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
REM Verify client hostname during SSL handshake
REM set SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION=false
REM SSL Certificates contain host/ip "peer name" information that is validated by default. Setting
REM this to false can be useful to disable these checks when re-using a certificate on many hosts
set SOLR_SSL_CHECK_PEER_NAME=true
REM Override Key/Trust Store types if necessary
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
```

When I am trying to start Solr, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1746)
    ... 7 more
```

Why do I get this error, when I clearly used "123456" in every step?

Comment: Stuck on this as well creating a self-signed cert the same way works but when I try to use a valid PFX file it just bombs out on me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is when you have special characters ie: ! @ # $  in the password you can't include these in a SOLR config file.